# Test Class issue for Standard Controller

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a Test class for Apex Standard Controller Class and am facing an issue while running the test class as it is unable to refer the relationship data. Please find the below code

**Apex Class:**

```
public class TestController {
   public Opportunity opportunity;

   public TestController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       this.opportunity = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
       //Even though the data for Opportunity.Account.BillingCity and BillingState is there in the Test class it is showing as null and if stmt is getting executed
       if(opportunity.Account.BillingCity == null || opportunity.Account.BillingState == null) {
           ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please fill details of following sections : '));
       }
   }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class TestControllerTest {
    static testMethod void UnitTest() {
        Account testAccount = new Account();
           testAccount.Name = 'AccountTest';
           testAccount.BillingCity = 'Pune';
           testAccount.BillingState = 'Maharashtra';
        insert testAccount;

        opportunity opportunitydata = new opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp ClosedOne',
                                        AccountId = testAccount.Id,
                                        Type = 'New Business',
                                        CloseDate = System.today(),
                                        StageName = 'Closed Won',
                                        ForecastCategoryName = 'Funnel',
                                        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD');
        insert opportunitydata;
        Test.startTest();
        TestController obj = new TestController(new ApexPages.StandardController (opportunitydata));
        Test.stopTest();
        //It should be zero as per the logic but still we are getting the Pagemessage as the If stmt is executed 
        System.assertEquals(0,ApexPages.getMessages().size());

    }
}
```

I have added debug statement and checked the records in the controller `this.opporunity.Account.BillingCity` is null whereas if we debug it in the Test class Account's BillingCity it is showing correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually populate the Account field before giving it to the controller, like this:

```
@isTest
private class TestControllerTest {
    static testMethod void UnitTest() {
        Account testAccount = new Account();
           testAccount.Name = 'AccountTest';
           testAccount.BillingCity = 'Pune';
           testAccount.BillingState = 'Maharashtra';
        insert testAccount;

        opportunity opportunitydata = new opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp ClosedOne',
                                        AccountId = testAccount.Id,
                                        Type = 'New Business',
                                        CloseDate = System.today(),
                                        StageName = 'Closed Won',
                                        ForecastCategoryName = 'Funnel',
                                        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD');
        insert opportunitydata;
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Assign account here so it is visible        //
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        opportunitydata.Account = testAccount;
        Test.startTest();
```

This will allow your controller to see the correct data.

Comment: I thought by just giving the Id might work. But the solution you provided worked. Thanks @sfdcfox